# How do I hook a Javascript function to a page-reload request OR a client-originated websocket disconnect?

Tags: javascript, websocket, reload

My problem: my page has a websocket handler. I handle a disconnect event (usually cause by a server restart) by displaying a "server disconnected, please reload" overlay.

However, when the **user** triggers a reload, the first thing the browser does is to disconnect the socket, which also triggers the disconnect event, so this overlay appears before being replaced by the new page. This is confusing, esp. since reloading the page may take a few seconds.

To clarify, what happens is

- user clicks Reload
- web socket gets disconnected by the browser

  - ws.onclose runs

    - … and displays a "please reload the page" alert overlay (or whatever)
- some time passes before the server gets around to assembling the new page
- page gets reloaded, overlay vanishes

I want to show that overlay only when the server is the disconnect's originator. Thus I either need to figure out which side did it, or hook into the page reload **before** it actually happens.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(window.performance)

{

    if(performance.navigation.type  == 1 )
          {
            console.log('page reloaded');
          }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API

Also you can write javascript function and set cookie.

```
function checkFirstVisit() {
  if(document.cookie.indexOf('mycookie')==-1) {
    // cookie doesn't exist, create it now
    document.cookie = 'mycookie=1';
  }
  else {
    // not first visit, so alert
    alert('You refreshed!');
  }
}
```

Call on body load event

```
   <body onload="checkFirstVisit()">
```

Comment: Umm, no. This solution tells me whether I had a reload after the new page is loaded. That's not useful. I need to run a script on the "old" page.

Comment: edited the question to (hopefully) explain the problem better